# How do I keep two UIScrollView instances zoomed to the same level?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have two instances of UIScrollView, and I want them to zoom at the same time.

Anyone have any experience doing that?

I'm using the `NSNotificationCenter` to tell my object when to zoom. Initially I thought I could somehow get at the currently visible rect, and just call `zoomToRect:`, but I don't see a way to do that. What I have now is setting the `zoomScale` and `contentOffset` properties. It looks like this:

```
- (void)registerForZoomNotifications {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(receiveZoomNotification:) 
                                             name:ZOOM_NOTIFICATION_IDENTIFIER 
                                           object:nil];
}

- (void)receiveZoomNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {

UIScrollView *currentScrollView = (UIScrollView*)[notification object];

// zoomLevel
[(UIScrollView*)self.view setZoomScale:currentScrollView.zoomScale animated:NO];

// contentOffset
[(UIScrollView*)self.view setContentOffset:currentScrollView.contentOffset animated:NO];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)pageScrollView {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ZOOM_NOTIFICATION_IDENTIFIER object:pageScrollView];

}
```

It's not working though, and seems terribly erratic. Ideas anyone? Should I be taking a different approach?

EDIT: I should clarify that both scroll views are not visible at the same time. It's not important that they scroll at the EXACT same time, only that ones scroll view is at the same zoom level (and visible rect) as the other after scrolling completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The erratic behavior I witnessed was because I wasn't sending a notification when I scrolled, only zoomed. When I added the following additional delegate method, everything worked correctly:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ZOOM_NOTIFICATION_IDENTIFIER object:scrollView];
}
```

Comment: I am also doing the same thing but can you let me know whats ZOOM_NOTIFICATION_IDENTIFIER does ? is it static or #define ??

Comment: in this example, `ZOOM_NOTIFICATION_IDENTIFIER` is a #define. I use the all capital convention for #defines. If I remember right, postNotificationName:object: takes an `NSString`.

Answer (score 7):

An easier way is to implement the UIScrollViewDelegate Protocol for your UIView control which manage the 2 UIScrollView2

in your .h file just add  in the @interface declaration

```
@interface yourUIViewControll : UIViewControll <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIScrollView *aUIScrollView;
    UIScrollView *bUIScrollView;
}
```

this way now you can use all the methods you need when user scroll or zoom one of the 2 UIScrollView
so, for example, you wanna know when one is zooming or scrolling and wanna let the other too zoom and scroll you need these 2 in particular

in .m:

```
// called when a UIScrollView is zooming:
    - (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)zoomViewInUse{
    // just to test in log window:
    // NSLog(@"changing zoom...  scrollViewInUse.zoomScale: %.5f", zoomViewInUse.zoomScale);
    //force both UIScrollViews to zoom at the new value
        aUIScrollView.zoomScale = zoomViewInUse.zoomScale;
        bUIScrollView.zoomScale = zoomViewInUse.zoomScale;
    }


// called when a UIScrollView is scrolling:
    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollViewInUse{
       // just to test in log window:
       //  NSLog(@"scrollViewInUse..contentOffset.x:%.1f", scrollViewInUse.contentOffset.y);
       //force both UIScrollViews to scroll at the new value
        aUIScrollView.contentOffset = scrollViewInUse.contentOffset;
        bUIScrollView.contentOffset = scrollViewInUse.contentOffset;
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm. This type of an approach would require me to change which class is my delegate. I have this kind of a heirarchy right now: `ParentClass->ScrollContainerClass`, the `ScrollContainerClass` is my delegate, and doesn't know anything about the other scroll views. (Hence the notifications.)

Comment: well, i guess that you can get access to ParentClass from ScrollContainerClass (self.delegate maybe? it could be an easy way), then you can manage a method in ParentClass and call it from any ScrollContainerClass when you zoom, and from that method zoom the other one too... so you have to make some more passages, but the meaning is the same...

Comment: Unless you have a reason not to, this is the correct approach.

Comment: @Moshe why would the delegate be preferable to observer? Does it change things to say that I have a variable number of scroll views, and they are programmatically created? I am actually coming around to this solution, because I now have an issue with the initial display of new scrollviews, since they are not all instantiated at the same time. (So some object needs to keep track of the current zoom and offset for all of them. Might as well be the parent.)

Comment: I up-voted your answer, because, while it wasn't the answer I picked, it's clearly still a fine way to do it.